# How to keep a dog pool insect free and safe to drink?

Tags: dogs

How can I keep my 40 gallon dog pool free from insects and swimmers whilst keeping it safe to drink?

I have tried dawn, but do not know if that is safe for the dog to drink.

Comment: You said 'I tried dawn', what does that mean? (Also welcome :) ) You can edit your question to add more information by clicking the 'edit' button.

Comment: please add more information where do you live,what have you tried so far.

Comment: @Henders I suspect "Dawn" is a reference to [Dawn Dish soap](https://dawn-dish.com/en-us)

Answer (score 2):

Just get a small net to catch any dead insects or leaves and you should be fine. While not necessarily fully hygienic, that's perfectly fine for dogs (and in theory humans as well).

If there are living insects in there... ignore them, unless they're in some way toxic or so. I'd also recommend exchanging the water like once a week depending on temperatures etc. If you change it regularly, the number of insects should decrease as well.

Always remember there's nobody out there to "clean" lakes or rivers and animals still bath and drink in them.

Answer (score 0):

### Make it a small pond.

40 galons is quite a bit. And to refresh that much water seems a bit wasteful. Why not make it a small pond with a balanced eco system?

Best would be to match the local wildlife. A few water plants for keeping the pond clear and a few fishes to keep the water bugs in check. Heck, if you are in central America you might even use guppies as mosquito control. You would still need to replenish / filter the water, but you will need to do that anyway.

Comment: I am not sure this is viable for 40 gallons.  Many people use small children's pools that are about 4 feet across with 6 inches of water, they hold about 40 Gallons.  The pools are disposable and don't hold up well.